# What is the average distance in standard deviations between two points selected at random from a normal curve?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Say I have a normal distribution of heights with average 150cm and standard deviation 10cm. If I select two people at random, what would be the expected difference in their heights?

I've tried to google for the answer, but I couldn't really find anything I could understand.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you select two people *indepdently* at random, and that you mean the absolute value of the difference (the expectation of the signed difference is $0$ by symmetry):

The difference of two independent normal random variables with variance $\sigma^2$ is itself a normal random variable with variance $2\sigma^2$. So the question reduces to the expectation of the absolute value of a normal random variable with mean $0$ and variance $2$, which is
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x| \frac1{2\sqrt\pi} e^{-x^2/4}\,dx = \frac2{\sqrt\pi} \text{ standard deviations}.
$$

Comment: Ah great - thank you!